# How to account for new columns being added to a table but not for all the dates?

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I have a script like this

An inital API call and then the following script

```
df22 = spark.read.json("dbfs:/mnt/servicenow/bronze/d******/"+file_timestamp[:8]+"/d******.json")
df23 = df22.select("result.*")

cols1 = ["request_number","requested_for","application",",not_found","application_changes","rto_met"]
a = []
```

The code was running fine before i included "rto_met" which was a new addition to the table but after this, it gives me the error that column "rto_met" was not found. If i look at the json file, column was only included from last two weeks and not before till Jan 1st 2020.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the additional columns? If you have 2 versions of the data, then you should have 2 versions of processing scripts.

Comment: I have to eventually visualize it in Power BI after including those additional columns in the existing table. The only problem is, the additional columns are only included for the most recent weeks and not backdated

Comment: Again same question, if you have 2 versions of data, then what exactly are you going to show in Power BI for the data that you don't have those columns?

Comment: Null or NA for those row items

Comment: There you go. You can add a check to see if `rto_met` is in your pulled table or not, and if not, you can create an empty column with name `rto_met`, then just proceed as if you already have it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, how can i include the check in reading the json file? A bit new to the field

Comment: Well that's up to you. You can either do it before reading by checking the date, or you can do it after reading into pandas data frame by checking the number of columns.